# determine selected items in a List of SelectListItem using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am attempting to use Linq to determine the selected item/s in a List of SelectListItem

```
var selected = (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EmployeeSupervisorUserId.Where(x => x.Selected);
```

I am receiving

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically
>   dispatched operation  without first casting it to a delegate or
>   expression tree type

Comment: There is literally no way that `ViewBag.EmployeeSupervisorUserId.Where(x => x.Selected)` can be cast to a `List`. I am not sure exactly what that error means - but I do know that you are asking for something to occur that won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your expression before using `Where`

```
var selected = ((List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EmployeeSupervisorUserId).Where(x => x.Selected);
```